# In R how to conserve a date when making an array?

Tags: r, date

I want to make an array with 3 rows and 1 column. I want all the entries to be 2000-01-01. But when I attempt it changes to 10957

`array(data = as.Date("2000-01-01", origin = "2000-01-01"), dim = c(3,1))`

Comment: You can store it in a `list` instead of a matrix or if you need a `matrix`, then wrap it in a `list` and then store in a matrix i.e. `m1 <- array(list(as.Date("2000-01-01", origin = "2000-01-01")), c(3, 1))` check the `str(m1)`

Comment: Do you need an `array`? Would a `data.frame` do the job?

Answer (score 1):

A two dimensional array is a matrix and a matrix discards all the additional attributes from an atomic vector which is passed, `class` is an attribute of dates which is removed and what remains is just a number.

You can store dates as character or numeric.

```
m <- array("2000-01-01", dim = c(3, 1))
m
#             [,1]        
#[1,] "2000-01-01"
#[2,] "2000-01-01"
#[3,] "2000-01-01"
```

If you want to do some processing on it you can convert it to date then.

```
as.Date(m)
#[1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2000-01-01"
```